# Avoid ember to wrap my component

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-components

This is my component:

```
{{#link-to routeName class="list-group-item"}}
  <i class="fa {{icon}} fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; {{text}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Which I use:

```
<div class="list-group">
  {{icon-link routeName="my-account" icon="fa-user" text="Personal details"}}
...
</div>
```

The expected html is:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="xxx">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Personal details
  </a>
...
</div>
```

But because ember wraps the components in a div, the bootstrap rules do not apply anymore and the list-group has a wrong style.

If I change the component tag to `a`, and remove `link-to` from the component template, I loose the flexibility of `link-to` - and I do not know how to set attributes (href, class) in the containing tag.

It seems I can not use an Ember component for this then? Or is there a way to tellink ember no to wrap my component in a `div`, or anything else really: in order for the CSS to work, the markup structure must not be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this myself but apparently you can create custom link-to components by extending `Ember.LinkComponent`. Something like this might work...

```
// app/components/icon-link.js

export default Ember.LinkComponent.extend({
  classNames: ["list-group-item"],

  icon: null,
  text: null,
})
```

...

```
// app/templates/components/icon-link.hbs

<i class="fa {{icon}} fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; {{text}}
```

...

```
// wherever

{{icon-link 'my-account' icon="fa-user" text="Personal details"}}
```

Here's a related blog post which may help you also - http://til.hashrocket.com/posts/faef1058c3-inheriting-from-linkcomponent-in-ember-is-amazing

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I am looking for! I am trying this, and get a strange error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`. I have double checked everything, and both template and javascript seem to be ok. The blogpost you are linking to is unfortunately not linking to a working application or a jsbin, which would help a lot.

Comment: Never mind: it is working, but you need ember~2.0.0. The thing is, the latest ember-cli is stuck on ember@1.13.13. You need to manually upgrade ember and ember-data in your bower.json - which is a gamble, since there are other 7-8 packages related to ember, and I am not sure if they are playing nice together. I can tell you that upgrading all ember-related packages to the latest version does not work.